# File upload in AngularJS causes browser out of memory error

Tags: javascript, json, memory-management, angular.js, network-file-transfer

I have an AngularJS code to perform upload of files. At first I thought it works OK but when I've tried to upload bigger files (e.g. 5 files, 10 MB each) then I saw that this code has very poor performance regarding memory handling.

For example: when I attach 5 files (10 MB each = 50 MB in total) then peak browser process memory demand reaches 2 GB!
I've tested it in Firefox, Chrome and IE. Additionally, in Chrome when browser process reaches 3 GB of memory committed then the page crashes.
In Firefox I can see an error in console when trying to upload more than 80 MB at once: 
`out of memory`

I've tried to modify the parts where the actual request is made and removed `data: JSON.stringify(formattedData)` which was the first bottleneck. And it turned out that `stringify`ing is redundant there.

But the second bottleneck still exists which is the function `binArrayToJson` which takes the ArrayBuffer and reads the data into the byte array.

```
var binArrayToJson = function (binArray) {
   var str = [binArray.length];
   for (var i = 0, binLength = binArray.length; i < binLength; i++) {
   str[i] = binArray[i];
   }
   return str;
}

var applyAttachments = function (data1) {
   angular.forEach(data1,
       function (value, key) {
           if (key === "Attachments") {
               for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
                   if (value[i].file) { //already saved item don't contain 'file' property
                       var reader = new FileReader();

                       reader.onloadend = (function (f) {
                           return function (result) {

                               var arrayBuffer = result.target.result;
                               value[f].fileContent = binArrayToJson(new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer));
                               value[f].isUploaded = true;
                           };
                       })(i);

                       reader.readAsArrayBuffer(value[i].file);
                   }
               }
           }
       });
};


var createMVCModel = function (output) {
   var defaultStringValue = "";
   return {
       id: output.id,
       Name: output.name || defaultStringValue,
       Status: output.status || "Draft",
       Date: output.date || null
       Attachments: output.attachments || []
   };
};

var saveModel = function (data, url) {
   var formattedData = createMVCModel(data);
   var deferred = $q.defer();

   applyAttachments(formattedData);

   var check = function () {
       if (allNewFilesUploaded(formattedData) === true) {
           $http({
                   url: url,
                   method: "POST",
                   data: formattedData,
                   headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
               })
               .then(function (result) {
                       deferred.resolve(result);
                   },
                   function (result) {
                       deferred.reject(result);
                   });
       } else {
           setTimeout(check, 1000);
       }

   }
   check();
   return deferred.promise;
};
```

I omitted the parts where the following requirements are being met:

- checking number of files (limit is 10)
- checking size of each file (limit is 10 MB each)
- checking permitted file extensions
- sending rest of the (text) data along with files to the server (ASP.NET MVC method)

Comment: Sounds like a question for StackOverflow because the code doesn't work as intended, which makes it off-topic here.

Comment: @wOxxOm If the code works for small files, but fails to scale, then it could be acceptable here on Code Review.

Answer (score 2):

Marshaling the file contents as a byte array is obviously problematic.

Browsers can easily upload files through HTML forms, with

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file">
</form>
```

Adapt the server to handle file uploads using that mechanism, then develop a replacement [AJAX client](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5976031/1157100).